# using part of a theme in another theme

Tags: theme-development

So I have a divi theme I have been using to build a site... only thing is I wanted a portfolio section that was quite specific so I ended up using the wanchai wordpress template.  I have both templates but want to merge the portfolio functionality from wanchai to divi theme... can anyone help on what I need to do ?

the portfolio has a php file , and a javascript file associated with it from inspection.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be an easy or "some clicks" way to archive your goal.

In theory, you will need these things to make the portfolio function work:

1. function registers portfolio post type.
2. Template file for that post type.
3. Custom metabox for that post type. - For adding custom fields.
4. Javascript file for handing animations, events... for displaying portfolio at front-end. (optional).
5. Additional CSS.
6. Theme options. (optional)

For the number 3, you can add your metabox via `functions.php`. Or you can using CMB2 to easily add metabox to your custom post type. If you prefer plugin, Advanced Custom Fields or Metabox.io are good choices.